# YTPlayerView.m pauseVideo() does not pause the video if controls = 0

Tags: youtube-api

Issue summary:

YTPlayerView.m pauseVideo() does not pause the video nor cause a state change to Paused if the video is loaded with controls = 0.

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Load a video with loadWithVideoId:(NSString *)videoId playerVars:(NSDictionary *)playerVars

UPDATE - playerVars are:

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                             @"autohide"        :   @1,
                             @"autoplay"        :   @0,
                             @"controls"        :   @0,
                             @"enablejsapi"     :   @1,
                             @"playsinline"     :   @1,
                             @"fs"              :   @0,
                             @"showinfo"        :   @0,
                             @"modestbranding"  :   @1,
                             @"rel"             :   @1
                             };
```

2. call playVideo()
3. call pauseVideo()

Expected output:

The video should start playing, then pause. The callback on state change should be called when the video starts playing and again when it pauses.

Actual results:

The video starts playing but does not pause.
The state change callback is called when the video starts playing, but not thereafter.

Notes:

Immediately after loading the video, if the native YouTube controls are used *first*, then the API calls work correctly thereafter. So, if you load the video and then tap on the UIWebView to start playback, and then tap on it again to pause playback, the video starts and pauses correctly and the state change callback is called correctly. After doing this the playVideo() and pauseVideo() methods work as expected. However if you don't do this first then pauseVideo() will not work.

This may possibly be related to v0.1.3 as it was working correctly in a previous version.

---

Solved - this seems to be an Xcode simulator problem, as it works OK on a device (iPad 2 and iPad Mini).
Simulator version 9.0 (SimulatorApp-602 CoreSimulator-159)
Xcode version 7.0 beta (7A120f)

Comment: What are your playerVars?

Comment: You should create an issue at  https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues.